# I don't have a title bar in Android studio. When I press the Show System UI button, my title bar does not appear

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio

Look the image:
image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KROXw.png)

## I don't know what code this is caused by. That's why I will only share themes.xml codes.

```
//Themes.xml

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.TitleBarSettings" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.TitleBarSettings" parent="Base.Theme.TitleBarSettings" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is another way to add a default toolbar to your app while setting your parent theme same as:

```
parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

activity_main.xml

by following this approach you don't need to change background color from the java code but you can easily change background color as a simple attribute of toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1F6C23"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }
}
```

see the official documentation here :
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/appbar/setting-up

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="Base.Theme.TitleBarSettings" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

You have set NoActionBar theme. Thats why it is not appearing.

use this as your parent theme:

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

It will have actionbar with the app name but it will not have 3 dotted menu on the right side.

For changing the color of the ActionBar add following code in your onCreate of the mainActivity.

```
// Define ActionBar object
        ActionBar actionBar;
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        // Define ColorDrawable object and parse color
        // using parseColor method
        // with color hash code as its parameter
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable
                = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0F9D58"));

        // Set BackgroundDrawable
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

You can change the **"#0F9D58"** to any color code you want.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You said that you don't have a title bar in app, and when you press the button it doesn't show the ActionBar? So how you can expect it to appear when you don't have one? And please specify what activity you chose when creating the project? Empty Activity? Empty View Activity? or any other ?

Comment: @ÖzcanBayram You can always create a custom action Bar... if you wan the one let me know i will post the code here.

Comment: See the image link above. It looks that way. But I want to see a bar above where the title of the project is written. In a classic default way. Since I'm new to this, I need your help.

Comment: "You have set NoActionBar theme. Thats why it is not appearing." What should I write instead?

Comment: use this as your parent theme : **parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"**. It will have actionbar with the app name but it will not have 3 dotted menu on the right side.

Comment: Thank you very much :))) . So how can I adjust its color?